# How to add Field data in between <td> in PHP EMAILER?

Tags: php

I have created a PHP form which is working fine without adding any html `table` on that. While I am applying `table` to make the emailer better look, I am receiving email without `form` Field Data. How to solve this?

How to mention the field name inside `<td>`. ? Eg:

```
<td>'.$field_name."\n";</td>
```

Comment: Using html in email content create multiple times more problems and security threads than it solves. You ask ultimate trust from the receivers. Anyone with the smalels thought about security will either delete such mails right away or be annoyed, since it requires a few clicks to view the actual content in intelligent email programs that try to protect users from the security risks raised by such messages. Send plain text emails, that is just fine for 99.9% of all messages.

Comment: @arkascha - All maintstream email services display HTML-formatted just fine (within the limitations imposed).

Comment: You did not understand the term "security risks". This is not about being able to display them. It is about a risk for people receiving such messages.

Comment: What risk? That it will look bad?

Comment: A security risk has nothing to do with look and feel. The risk is that arbitrary content and scripts can be referenced or embedded in such messages. That means that anyone looking at such a message risks his system to be infected. HTML email messages are the number one source of malware infections these days.

Comment: Sorry, script content is stripped out of any HTML or the message is blocked. This is part of the "limitations" I mentioned. HTML allowed in email is really a rudimentary subset of regular HTML. This is irrelevant to the OP's question anyhow, who presumably is not doing anything nefarious with his table-formatted email content.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like that:

```
$field_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$field_age= htmlspecialchars($_POST['age']);
$body_message .= '<tr><td>GUEST NAME </td><td>'.$field_name.'</td></tr><tr><td>AGE </td><td>.'$field_age.'</td></tr>';
```

I assume that your form uses POST method and field names are name and age.

Comment: Dear Marcin,

Thanx for your quick response.
Following is the sample code as you requested.

$body_message .= '<tr><td>GUEST NAME </td><td><?php echo $field_name; ?></td></tr>';
$body_message .= '<tr><td>AGE </td><td><?php echo $field_age; ?></td></tr>';

If i add this in my emailer.php, I receive emails perfectly. But the form field datas (Name & Age) not receiving in email.

Comment: Thanks alot Dear.U saved my time.. 

I have 1 more question, which is not looks easy for me..

I have to send copy of this email to the visitor along with random number&alphabets (eg:reference code for registeration). If possible, can u help me on this?

Comment: In that case please accept answer as solving your problem and create another thread describing your problem in details

Comment: Hi Marcin,

Here I posted my query as separate post. You are welcome to add your valuable comment there.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453726/auto-generate-random-number-in-php/23453760